# is there something like `%` but for matching double quotes

Tags: macro, delimiter-matching

I'm working on some HTML files that are formatted weirdly. Each individual class is on a separate line which makes the file (imo) difficult to read.

Something like:

```
<div class="
  classA
  classB
  classC
" id="xxx">
```

I would like to use a macro that does the following:

1. find the next occurence of `class="`
2. select everything inside the matching `"`
3. do <kbd>J</kbd> to join all those lines together

If I would deal with `{` instead of `"` i could do something like
<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
But this doesn't work for `"` or `'` as far as i can tell.
I tried doing <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> but this only seems to find `"` on the same line.

I'm pretty sure I can make this work using regex but I was wondering if there's something simpler that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(N.B. I'm not sure if by "macro" you mean a mapping or a recording, so I've just included the keystrokes in the below, to match what you did in your question.)*

It might not work in general, but for the specific example given, you can use a regular search: <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: oh waw, thats such a simple solution that i just didn't think of. Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to install the [target](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) Vim plugin that extend the `i"` text object such that it works on multiple line (among other improvements).

Comment: Nice, i didn't know that plugin existed. I do think i like the simplicity of @Rich's answer though. But thanks for the plugin suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. With 1.3k star it is a "classic" :-)